# с++ Математическое уровнение

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверьте пожалуйста правильно ли записан пример

```
fi = (pow(sin(x * x), 3)) + (pow(pow(a , 6 - tan(b)), 1.0 / 3));
```

Comment: Нет, не правильно.

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy а как правильно?

Comment: Там `b`, тут `6`. Разница кривая.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная "а" в степени "b", а не шесть.
После 6 (та, которая должна быть "b") отсутствует закрывающая скобочка.
Да и вообще скобок многовато.
В итоге...

fi = pow (sin (x * x), 3) + pow (pow (a, b) - (tan (b)), 1.0 / 3);